# Remove file name from url in 2nd case not work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove a file name from url, where url is: `mysite.com/project.php?page=AAA` and here want to remove `project.php?page=`. So previously I removed successfully another file name from url by below method where url was: `mysite.com/userinfo.php?user=111` and removed `userinfo.php?user=`

htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ userinfo.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But now when I am going apply same method for remove `project.php?page=`. Its not work.

I tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ project.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here is all htaccess

```
#Remove php#
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

#Remove Userinfo#
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ userinfo.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Do I correctly understand that you want url mysite.com/userinfo.php?user=111 to be redirected to mysite.com/111 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect from mysite.com/userinfo.php?user=111 to mysite.com/111 it is enough 2 lines:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} user=([^?&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^userinfo.php$ /%1? [R,L]
```